# Downloading files outside the webroot

Tags: php, apache, plesk

OK, firstly apologies as I realise that this is a topic which has been covered many times before - believe me I know, I've read all of the previous questions and answers and still can't get this to work.

I have a folder containing downloadable files. For security purposes I've located this file outside the webroot. However, despite my best efforts, I can't get my php script to download the file.

I'm using a Linux VPS Apache Server using Plesk 11.

The (simplified) file structure is as follows. The `httpdocs` folder is the webroot. The `private/uploadedfiles` folder is where I want to download from.

```
-var
 - www
  - vhosts
   - mydomain.org.uk
    - httpdocs (webroot)
    - private
     - uploadedfiles
```

I'm using a jQuery ajax call to pass the filename to a PHP script called `downloadscript.php`. This script sits within the `httpdocs` webroot. The script is as follows:

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST['fbpath'];
$path = '/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.org.uk/private/uploadedfiles/' . $filename;

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path);
exit;

?>
```

The ajax call is working with no issues, but I'm getting the following error message on my PHP logs:

```
 PHP Warning: readfile(/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.org.uk/private/uploadedfiles/filename.docx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I have checked, double checked and triple checked and the file definitely exists on inside the `uploadedfiles` folder.

I have also checked that it isn't an `open_basedir` restriction issue - I'm pretty sure it isn't.

I'm sure there's something really simple I'm missing - where am I going wrong?

As an additional extra, I haven't written the script for uploading files yet - is there anything I should know in advance before going ahead with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the rights of the folder `uploadedfiles` and its contents... It could be your webserver or PHP may not access the files because of the permissions set on them...

Comment: I've opened up all permissions (via my FTP client) - the permissions line currently reads `drwxrwxrwx`for both the `private` and `uploadedfiles` folders and `-rwxrwxrwx` for the files stored within. Is this what you meant? If so, it doesn't appear to have worked. If you meant something different, could you let me know? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much trial and error, I appear to have solved the problem.

The issue was in using jQuery/Ajax.

When I changed the way the `downloadscript.php` file is accessed to a direct `$_GET` request from the link on the page, it worked a treat.

Anyway, thanks for your help everyone!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem once. It's not really a solution but a workaround for you. What I did is downloading my files into a tmp folder inside the webroot. Then, each hour, or day, a cron job (scheduled task on Plesk) is run on the server, copying every files from my temporary folder into another folder outside webroot using the linux copy command.

However, you can take a look here for what you want:

- [how to access file from outside root directory in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896429/how-to-access-file-from-outside-root-directory-in-php)
- [How can I    allow a user to download a file which is stored outside of the webroot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345322/how-can-i-allow-a-user-to-download-a-file-which-is-stored-outside-of-the-webroot)
- [PHP display/download directory files outside the webserver root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382219/php-display-download-directory-files-outside-the-webserver-root)
- [[RESOLVED] download zip from outside the web root](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10313152-RESOLVED-download-zip-from-outside-the-web-root)

Hope this can help you.